# php curl_init() not working

Tags: php

am trying to send SMS using the url but it's not working the result is empty this is my code

```
$ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);

        /**
        * Ask cURL to return the contents in a variable
        * instead of simply echoing them to the browser.
        */

        //Using Proxy
        // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, '212.138.39.84:8080');
        //

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

        /**
        * Execute the cURL session
        */
$result = curl_exec ($ch);
                    /**
        * Close cURL session
        */
        curl_close ($ch);


         $result=explode("\n",$result);
         $result=$result[(count($result)-1)];
     $result;
```

can anyone help me ???

Comment: What is the error message? What is not working? What should happen? What happens?

Comment: errors? ... do you have curl installed?

Comment: no error it should send sms by the url link information but the result is null

Comment: write very first line php_info(); exit(); and see do you have curl library there?

Comment: do $url has any value???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
<?php 

    $ch = curl_init ($url);

     /*
      * Send SMS
      */
      curl_setopt ($ch , CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER , TRUE);
      curl_setopt($ch , CURLOPT_TIMEOUT , 30);

     /*
      * Execute command and send sms
      */

     $result = curl_exec ($ch);
?>
```

you can write below line for print out put

```
<?php
      echo "<pre>";
      print_r($result); 
      echo "</pre>";
?>
```

see output after parse or expload result.